# Regex - Matching a line but something wrong with /m?

Tags: regex, ruby

I'd trying to match the first of the following types of strings in an email:

```
On Nov 18, 2010, at 8:21 PM, SiteName wrote:

On Thu, Nov 18, 2010 at 8:21 PM, SiteName <notification@SiteName.com> wrote:
```

The first line matches correctly, but the 2nd does not. here's what I have so far:

```
mystring.sub(/^On \w+ \d+, \d+, at.* wrote:.*/m, '').strip
```

I can't figure out why the 2nd line is erroring. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For the second line you need:

```
mystring.sub(/^On \w+, \w+ \d+, \d+ at.* wrote:.*/m, '').strip
```

So combined you might use:

```
mystring.sub(/^On \w+(, \w+)? \d+, \d+,? at.* wrote:.*/m, '').strip
```

So I try this script:

```
puts "Holla

On Thu, Nov 18, 2010 at 8:41 PM, SiteNameHere <notification@mylongsitename.com>wrote:
> testttttttt
>
> On Thu, Nov 18, 2010 at 8:47 PM, Brett Hellman <bhellman1@gmail.com> wrote:
>>
>> Thanks for setting this up
>>
>> On Thu, Nov 18, 2010 at 8:46 PM, CompanyLine <notification@companyline.com> wrote:
>>>
>>> Steve Apple has created a new conversation on CompanyLine: Test 3 Regex issues
>>>
>>> The following people have been added as participants:
>>>
>>> - Steve Apple
>>> - Brett Hellman
>>
>".sub(/^On \w+(, \w+)? \d+, \d+,? at.* wrote:.*/m, '').strip
```

which yields

```
"Holla"
```

Is this not what you want?

Comment: Here's the line that just failed: "On Thu, Nov 18, 2010 at 8:41 PM, SiteNameHere <notification@mylongsitename.com>wrote:"    What does the /m do? I can't find that in the docs

Comment: The `m` stands for multiline - if you don't provide it the `.` will not match newline characters (`\n`).

Comment: Also if you keep facing problems you might want to post more info/code so we can see where's the problem and what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Jakub, it's breaking with GMAIL when sending an HTML email, versus  plain text, where it works just fine. Maybe requiring the line break is the issue ? /^

Comment: @Jakub, thanks but I'm not sure what else I'd post? Check this out: http://www.postbin.org/1iw2ycf    It shows the post from the email, what I'm doing is grabbing the PLAIN paramater, and trying to match that line above so I can get everything above as the reply.. thoughts?

Comment: Well wouldn't you need also `gsub` rather then `sub`? Also aren't the `>` characters causing a bit of a problem?

Comment: You thin it's the > characters causing the issue? Also, I noticed that in the postbin, the matching line doesn't have a blank line between the rest of the text. Could that be the issue? I didn't think I needed gsub since I only want to get the first match and take everything above. right?

Comment: I'm not sure what's not working for you. Do you get an error or no matches? I've updated the answer with my code and output.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma after 'Thu' and you aren't accounting for that.

edit:

Is there any reason for it to be so specific?  Why not just match and replace: `/^On.*at.*wrote:/`

edit again:

so after looking at your pastebin here is what i think you want:

`string.gsub(/\>+\sOn.*at.*wrote:\s/, '')`

that will clean out the arrows at the start of the line, the line itself, and the end of line so it should look like this:

```
> testttttttt
>
>>
>> Thanks for setting this up
>>
>>>
>>> Steve Apple has created a new conversation on CompanyLine: Test 3 Regex issues
>>>
>>> The following people have been added as participants:
>>>
>>> - Steve Apple
>>> - Brett Hellman
>>
>
```

Comment: re5et, there seems to be more going on, see below. Any ideas? thanks!